# How can I simplify this into a loop? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

Edit: I know this question is getting downvoted, but still would really appreciate any help.

I tried to simplify it to this, can it get simpler?

```
x(1) = 1;
y(1) = 0;
x(2) = x(1) - y(1)*10^(0)
y(2) = y(1) + x(1)*10^(0)

  for n=2:3
 x(n+1) = x(n) - y(n)*0.1
 y(n+1) = y(n) + x(n)*0.1

  end
  for n=3:8
 x(n+2) = x(n+1) - y(n+1)*0.01
 y(n+2) = y(n+1) + x(n+1)*0.01
  end
  for n=4:5
 x(n+7) = x(n+6) - y(n+6)*0.001
 y(n+7) = y(n+6) + x(n+6)*0.001    
  end
  for n=5:8
 x(n+8) = x(n+7) - y(n+7)*0.0001
 y(n+8) = y(n+7) + x(n+7)*0.0001

 end
```

Edit: Trying to implement Beaker's suggestion:

```
x(1) = 1;
y(1) = 0;
x(2) = x(1) - y(1)*1
y(2) = y(1) + x(1)*1
a=[x, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001]
 for n=2:16
     x(n+1) = x(n) - y(n)*0.1
     y(n+1) = y(n) + x(n)*0.1
 end
 a*x(n+1)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simply asking for refactoring.

Comment: Please could I just get some direction? I've spent 9 hours just to get here. I would appreciate any advice/hints/tips anything.. I really need this! :/

Comment: @elbarto: You are using for loops where no for loops should be used (only one iteration hard coded, that's an assigment n=3 not a for loop), but when it should be used (same line of code with different indices) you don't use it

Comment: @Daniel I think I get what you mean, and its a punch to the face.

E.g for line:

`for n=2

 x(n+1) = x(n) - y(n)*0.1

 y(n+1) = y(n) + x(n)*0.1

 x(n+2) = x(n+1) - y(n+1)*0.1

 y(n+2) = y(n+1) + x(n+1)*0.1`

I can simplify to 

`n=2:3

x(n+1) = x(n) - y(n)*0.1

y(n+1) = y(n) + x(n)*0.1`

Comment: Oh boy... There is much hard-coding and *useless* for loop here that I'm actually going to scream

Comment: If you're ever tempted to loop over `n` when the only thing you're computing is `x(n+8), y(n+8)`, you're doing it wrong. If you change every one of those left-hand sides to `x(n), y(n)` you'll see that you're calculating the same exact thing every time, except for the multiplier, and that you're calculating `x(2)` through `x(16)`. So why would you not have a loop `for n=2:16`?

Comment: @beaker I would have done that ordinarily, but I wasn't sure how to treat the part where I'm multiplying certain aspects by (10^0), (10^-1), (10^-2) etc

Comment: I don't see any pattern to the multiplier, so I'd simply have a vector `a=[x, 1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, ...]` where the value of `x` doesn't matter because we'll never use it. Then `x(n) = ... * a(n)`.

Comment: Incidentally, if that was the part you were having trouble with, it would have been better to ask that question rather than make us tease out the logic behind all these `for` loops.

Comment: Yes, the "pattern" to the multiplier is predetermined by a set of integers which i derived from another code.
In this case my set of integers needed for the multipliers is

`[1,2,6,2,4]`
So 1 time for 10^0, twice for 10^-1, six times for 10^-2 and so on

i apologise if my question was poorly asked, although I came to learn more about what i actually needed as i read these comments

Comment: @beaker so I've edited my original post, trying to implement what you were saying, but I don't think I quite have it. Could you help me where I've got it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting closer. Here's what I'd do:

```
x(1) = 1;
y(1) = 0;
%// x(2) and y(2) will be computed in loop
%// my a[] vector was off in the comments
a=[1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001];
for n=2:16
   x(n) = x(n-1) - y(n-1)*a(n); %// multiplier goes here...
   y(n) = y(n-1) + x(n-1)*a(n); %// and here.
end
```

You snuck in the `x(n+1) =` and `y(n+1) =`. I have no idea why you would want to do that, so I rewrote it. Output is:

```
x =

 Columns 1 through 8:

   1.00000   1.00000   0.90000   0.79000   0.77810   0.76612   0.75406   0.74193

 Columns 9 through 16:

   0.72972   0.71744   0.71620   0.71497   0.71484   0.71472   0.71460   0.71447

y =

 Columns 1 through 8:

   0.00000   1.00000   1.10000   1.19000   1.19790   1.20568   1.21334   1.22088

 Columns 9 through 16:

   1.22830   1.23560   1.23632   1.23703   1.23710   1.23718   1.23725   1.23732
```

Comment: this gives me an error:

Attempted to access x(2); index out of bounds because numel(x)=1.

Error in beakerscorrection (line 7)
   x(n+1) = x(n) - y(n)*a(n); %// multiplier goes here...

So i changed `n=2:16` to `n=1:16`, but the end values I get are completely off

Comment: working on the code. i'll get it working and get back to you.

Comment: You're exceedingly generous beaker. I wish I could Reward you, I think a bounty will be available in 2 days, I will add that and give it to you.

thank you! I'm up all night, as I will submit this in precisely 12 hours

Comment: You changed my `x(n) = ` to `x(n+1) =` and I didn't notice. That was throwing the indices off, so I changed it back to my version.

Comment: whoops, sorry. What is the purpose of setting x = zeros(1,16) and y=x by the way?

Comment: I threw that in to preallocate the vectors because you were getting the index out of bounds error. I didn't understand why you were getting it at the time, but I hadn't seen the `x(n+1) =` part yet. I'll take it out. The code runs fine without it.

Comment: And a reward isn't really necessary. Just think of it as my Code Beautification effort for the day. :)

Comment: No worries, I just ran the code without it and it's fine as well.

I have ONE final question, and then I'll leave you alone I promise :P.

this may seem obvious, but if I want to change the multiplies now, so in this instance we had  `[1,2,6,2,4]`, and I want to change it to `[3, 1, 6, 5 ,2]`

Do i  just need to alter the vector `a` accordingly?

eg in this instance

`a = [1, 1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.001...]`?

The first two 1's in `a` are confusing me a little, as to their origins

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74045/discussion-between-beaker-and-elbarto).

Comment: Just be sure to accept the answer when you get a chance.

Comment: You could also simplify `a`: `a=[1, 1, 1e-1 * ones(1,4), 1e-2 * ones(1,6), 1e-3 * ones(1,2), 1e-4 * ones(1,4)];`